# Where is the WCF's ABC in the VS2012' azure WCF sample?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

It will be a dummy question, but:

When i create a WCF service lib in vs 2012, in the app.config I can find information about the service, like this.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
```

But when I create an azure wcf project (hosted in a webrole), i could not find any information in the web.config about this. Where can i find them? Where is the line, which starts the service?

Thanks for your answer, and sorry for my english.

T

Answer (score 0):

Look in the web.config located in the root of the WCFWebRole you created.

Comment: OK. I noticed, the there is a config file, but it doesnt even have a servicemodel section. Anyway, thnaks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably it should be like in [Guidance for Using WCF in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh848261.aspx):

```
<ServiceDefinition name="MyService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
   <WebRole name="WebRole1">
      …
      <Endpoints>
         <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" localPort="80" />
      </Endpoints>
   </WebRole>
   …
</ServiceDefinition>
```